# Inserting hyphen in between strings as per the given format

Tags: python

I have a string like `s_t = "ABCD1234"`.

Now I have a format `XXX-X-00-00`.

And I want to convert the string to the above format.
i.e. `ABC-D-12-34`
Here `00` indicates number and `X` indicates string type.

I am following the below approach:

```
'-'.join([s_t[0:3],s_t[3],s_t[4:6],s_t[6:8]])
```

And this is giving correct result. However, I want this thing to be dynamic.

I am trying this:

```
l=[]
for i in s.split('-'):
  l_i = len(i)
  l_split = l.append(l_i)
```

And then

```
s_f = '-'.join([s_t[0:l[0]],s_t[l[0]],s_t[l[0]+1:l[0]+1+l[2]]])
```

But again this is not a dynamic approach. How can I use `enumerate(s_t)` effectively?

Comment: What should it return if the string cannot be formatted to the given format ? something like `input_string = "ABC" ; format = "XX-0"` where C is not a number.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic? what are expected outputs for some inputs

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the "dynamic approach" should not be dependent on the hard-coded numbers and lengths, it is also possible to adjust dynamically according to the split part lengths.

Code:

```
s_t = "ABCD1234"
format = "XXX-X-00-00"

def form(s_t, format):
    format_parts = format.split('-')
    extracted_parts = []
    start_index = 0
    for part in format_parts:
        length = len(part)
        extracted_parts.append(s_t[start_index:start_index+length])
        start_index += length

    return '-'.join(extracted_parts)

f = form(s_t, format)
print(f)
```

Output:

```
ABC-D-12-34
```